# increment an integer split in an array recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, integer

Imagine you have integers split into arrays like 100 -> [1, 0, 0]

How do you write a **recursive** function that increments the long integer. eg incr([9, 9]) -> [1, 0, 0]?

I know how to do it non recursively.

Comment: Please try and improve the title: in its first revision, it contains two articles in a row.

Comment: `I know how to do it non recursively.` (Present (a sketch of) your non-recursive approach.) A given iterative algorithm can be turned into a recursive one "mechanically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample implementation of @Mbo's algorithm in Python:

```
def addOne(a, ind, carry):
    if ind<0:
        if carry > 0:
            a.insert(0, carry)
    else:
        n = a[ind] + carry
        a[ind] = n%10
        carry = n/10
        addOne(a, ind-1, carry)


n = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
a = []
if n == 0:
    a.append(0)

while n>0:
    a.append(n%10)
    n = n/10

a = list(reversed(a))
print "Array", a

# performing addition operation
addOne(a,len(a)-1,1)
print "New Array", a
```

*Note:* I am sending `1` as the `carry` initially, because we want to add 1 to the number.

**Sample Input/Output**

```
Enter a number:  99
Array [9, 9]
New Array [1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: If I set n=99 I get len(a) -> 327

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode

```
function Increment(A[], Index)
   if Index < 0
       A = Concatenation(1, A)
   else
        if (A[Index] < 9)
            A[Index] = A[Index] + 1
        else
           A[Index] = 0
           Increment(A, Index - 1)
```

call

```
  Increment(A, A.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do with the following JS function, which is even a tail call optimized recursive one.

```js
var arr = [7,8,9],
    brr = [9,9,9];

function increment(a,r = []){
  return a.length ? (a[a.length-1] + 1) % 10 ? (a[a.length-1]++,a.concat(r))
                                             : increment(a.slice(0,a.length-1),r.concat(0))
                  : [1].concat(r);
}
console.log(increment(arr))
console.log(increment(brr))
```

Please keep in mind that for easy readability purposes i have used `increment(a.slice(0,a.length-1),r.concat(0))` however best would be to do the job like `increment(a.slice(0,a.length-1),(r.push(0),r))` which would boost the speed of incrementing a 10K 9 items array i.e. `[9,9,...9]` from ~1800msec to ~650msec. Also instead of `[1].concat(r)` you may choose use `(r.unshift(1),r)` which has a slight performance boost on FF (figures below 600msec) but may be not so in Chrome, yet more over you will not be creating a new array but pass a reference to `r`.